# Why doesn't the user input get put in the list?

Tags: discord.py

So I'm trying to put the user input in a list. So the user runs the command, it asks for the user's name and id. Then the user enters their info. and its' stored in a list. Am I doing anything wrong?

```py
@client.command()
async def add(ctx):
      await ctx.send("Please ONLY enter your name and student id. (ex. FirstName LastName 000000)")

      def check(msg):
          return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

      msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
      msg_id = msg.content
      ids = [""]
      ids.append(msg_id)
      await ctx.send("Thank you. Your id will be added ASAP.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add something to a list, it should be empty to begin with, this makes things much easier. Also, it makes little sense to keep this list inside the `command`, instead put it on top of the code, so it doesn't interfere with the code.

Since your list already contains `""` we empty the list (`[]`) and define it over the `command`.

**The complete code:**

```py
ids = [] # Empty list

@client.command()
async def add(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Please ONLY enter your name and student id. (ex. FirstName LastName 000000)")

    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    msg_id = msg.content
    ids.append(msg_id)
    await ctx.send("Thank you. Your id will be added ASAP.")
    print(ids) # Here we check the list
```

*Also make sure your code is indented correctly!*

Comment: Just one more question. Is it be possible to somehow automatically make the input the user puts into a command? ex. input: John San 987690, then a command called John San is automatically made and it prints the user id.

Comment: @Arikakate I do not think that this is possible in an easy way, you would have to use something I call `custom command` which also uses a database